# How to Re-Check Permissions on Resume

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, onresume

My application crashes if users enable the location permission through the app, then head to their phone's settings and disable the permission there. I have tried fixing this by checking the permissions through onResume but can't seem to get it right. Other solutions on StackOverflow haven't worked.

The following code runs within my onCreate() and checks for location permissions:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //check which API users are running.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    //location permission dialog
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
                }
            }
```

My onRequestPermissionsResult():

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The app requires location permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is my onResume() code within the same fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updatePermissions();
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        requestLocationUpdates();
    }
}

public void updatePermissions(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
       //check which API users are running.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            //location permission dialog
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

}
```

The app crashes with the error: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 at fluo.tuki10.fragments.MapFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(MapFragment.java:232)

which is the line

```
           if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

I feel like the solution is to implement a better onResume() that checks for permissions after users modify them outside the app. Unfortunately my code falls short

Comment: `checkSelfPermission` will cause your Activity to go in `Pause`. So this can go into infinite recursion if user disallow permission with `Never Ask Again`.

Comment: @Marios has answered correctly. You will need to check the length of the array before querying information at a specific index. You can check that Android developer docs also recommend the same. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting visit the section with the title "Handle the permissions request response"

Comment: @ADM What should I replace that with?

Answer (score 1):

An advice, before comparing it with a head that is not without elements:

**if (grantResults.length> 0)**

Comment: Will this fix the infinite loop problem that ADM described?

Comment: Probably not, but it is clear that if he had written the code as I advised him he would have seen:

Toast.makeText (getContext (), "The app requires location permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show ();

And he would have understood that there were no "answers" to the permits.

Comment: Do you know how to fix the loop bug? It still crashes

Comment: Many differents solutions, for first yiu can move you requestlocationupdate in a task, repeat 10/100 seconds a control permission...all logic code inside him, not in resume().